# What are the "quadric surfaces" to know to solve "Multivariable-Calculus" problems?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

This is kind of a "soft question". I'm asking about the quadric surfaces to know to be able to solve "Multivariable-Calculus" questions like this one: <<Given $K:=[(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: 2x^{2}+y^{2}\le z\le 4]$ find the curve $\gamma$, that has to be regular and simple, such that $supp(\gamma)=[(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^{3}}: x=0;z=y^{2}]\cap \partial K$>>. During the exercise I identified easily $[(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^{3}}: x=0;z=y^{2}]$ as a parabola in the $yz$ plane. But I had problems with $\partial K$, because I did not know that the equation $2x^{2}+y^{2}=z$ is the one of an "elliptic paraboloid" in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$. So, what (normal form, that is of the "original" quadric surface not stretched or rotated) equations like this one I'm supposed to know ?

Comment: "Calculus 3" is rather meaningless to a lot of participants here, and might mean different things to different people for have had a "calculus 3" course. I.e. it's school specific what it means.

Comment: I don't think you should have a need to memorise a whole bunch of surfaces

Comment: But, for example, how do you compute surface integrals without knowing that $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$ is a cone if that is the surface where you are integrating ?

Comment: I edited the questions because I think Henrik is right in his comment. Now I think "Multivariable-Calculus" suits better the context.

Comment: I guess parametrization works for the general case. Memorizing the simple ones like cones will help.

Comment: Using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/3d/36db4d6f88) helps a lot.